# Push Notification Plugin for Xamarin on receiving message

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have integrated push notification on Xamarin.Forms by using this plugin: https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification using our own web service on Rails.

What I need to do is to place the returned message properly in the notification. It currently is empty when it arrives.
The object returned is (default values from the documentation):

```
{
    "key": "value",
    "key2": "[\"array\",\"value\"]",
    "collapse_key": "do_not_collapse"
}
```

I reckon, this is where I format the message, but how do I do it?

```
void IPushNotificationListener.OnMessage(JObject arameters, DeviceType deviceType)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Message Arrived");
}
```

Comment: The JObject is where the data is. E.g. JObject["key"] should return value. What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: I'm trying to display the values on the notification. I've set the key "title": "Xamarin Push Notification" but it shows as the message. Here is the screenshot: http://s21.postimg.org/pf7p6favb/Nexus5_Kit_Kat_Screenshot_1.png

Comment: Btw, I'm using this https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup/wiki/GCM-Android as reference to my web server implementation.

Comment: @AdamPedley in case if you hadn't read my reply. :)

Comment: if you go to http://www.xamarinhelp.com/push-notifications/ and see the android message I send, this is what will show up in the message section of the notification center.

Comment: @AlexaMayer what Push notification plugin version, are you using?

Comment: @AdamPedley thanks, man. I'll check that out.

Comment: @RendyDelRosario currently on version 1.1.3

Comment: Please update the package that version had a big that was fixed